# Hybrid WebView Navigating and navigated events not responding in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, webview

well I have a Hybrid Webview that is calling a page and when it does I want to be able to handle the errors using the Navigated and Navigating event. This is my code below:

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="{Binding ThemeColor}" IsVisible="{Binding IsAdvert}">
                <local:HybridWebView x:Name="hybridWebView" Navigated="webOnEndNavigating" Navigating="Webview_Navigating" Uri="{Binding Source}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

Then in the .cs code where the event is is:

```
void webOnEndNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {
            progress.IsVisible = false;
            try
            {
                switch (e.Result)
                {
                    case WebNavigationResult.Cancel:

                        Navigation.PopAsync();
                        break;

                    case WebNavigationResult.Failure:

                        var isConnected = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;

                        if (isConnected != NetworkAccess.Internet)
                        {
                            Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Offline());
                            Navigation.PopAsync();
                        }
                        break;

                    case WebNavigationResult.Success:
                        mnu.IsEmptyList = false;
                        break;

                    case WebNavigationResult.Timeout:
                        Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Offline());
                        Navigation.PopAsync();
                        break;

                    default:
                        Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Offline());
                        Navigation.PopAsync();
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Offline());
                Navigation.PopAsync();
            }
        }

        private void Webview_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
        {           
           progress.IsVisible = true;           
        }
```

I have paced breakpoints at each end every case of my switch statement and even on the entry level of my event but I am not getting anything either on the successful rendering of the site I am calling or on the failure or time out. How best Can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

According to xamarin documents:

> On iOS, this HTML file resides in the Content folder of the platform
> project, with a build action of BundleResource. On Android, this HTML
> file resides in the Assets/Content folder of the platform project,
> with a build action of AndroidAsset.

I did a test based on this [sample](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/CustomRenderers/HybridWebView) and the method can work. So, you can check your webpage to see if it's in the right place.

For more information, you can refer to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview